# Store memory content in class - C++

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

I'm trying to write a plugin for an application and I'm stuck where I need to read the contents from memory and store that in a class. I've been given the following:

```
UserInfo = 0x9F9648 
UserInfoSize = 0x560
```

That's the location of where the content is stored and I've been given the following class to store it in:

```
class CUserInfo
{
public:
    __int32 clientNum; //0x0000  
    __int32 Valid; //0x0004  
    char unknown8[4]; //0x0008
    char Name[16]; //0x000C  
    ... and some other properties
};
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the contents from the address location and store it in a class instance.

Anyone any idea how to do that??

Comment: Not really.  There's certainly nowhere to store 0x560 bytes' worth of stuff.

Comment: Store address in pointer and start reading to the end? @OliCharlesworth, You must be joking, right?

Comment: @AtoMerZ: Why would I be joking?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: maybe "... and some other properties" has the other 1348 bytes in it.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Are you suggesting that what the OP should be doing is simply memcpying the contents into an existing `CUserInfo` instance?  If so, that intention is certainly not clear from the question.  I read "I've been given the following class to store it in" to mean that `CUserInfo` is some sort of wrapper/container.

Comment: This is just too weird. With the offsets being given in the comments there's an obvious answer (something like the `memcpy` idea), but the obvious answer makes no sense in the context of an application plugin. Why the heck are they giving you a raw numeric address for the data if it's an application plugin? What kind of crazy API is that?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I don't know what the OP should be doing. Merely offering up a possibility, it looks like the OP has supplied offsets indicating potentially a packed representation in the class.

Comment: @AtoMerZ I know what has to be done. But i don't know how to do that... Like, do i store the pointer in a BYTE? Then create an instance of the CUserInfo class like so: --- BYTE memAdd = (BYTE*)0x9F9648; CUserInfo *cu = memAddr; --- Or something like that? But i also have to read the entire 0x0560 bytes, like you said. Could you (or anyone) perhaps give me an example? --- To others: This is an educational assignment. I just can't understand how to do it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, Because 0x560 = 1376 bytes? You could store it anywhere.

Comment: @w00: where did you get that address from?

Comment: @AtoMerZ: I interpreted the question as meaning that `CUserInfo` is some sort of wrapper class.  There's certainly nowhere to store 1376 bytes of stuff there (at least not in the fields the OP has shown us).

Comment: This is a bit dangerous. Just for curiosity, why do you have the address of the data without a pointer to stores it?. Remember the address of every variables will change in each execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reinterpret_cast<>` to convert an integer address into a pointer to any needed type, then dereference the pointer.

For example:

```
CUserInfo user_info;
user_info.clientNum = *(reinterpret_cast<__int32*>(0x9F9648));
```

Of course this is dangerous practice. You should be aware of access violation and alignment errors when you try to access an arbitrary memory address.

Answer (score 2):

If UserInfo an CUserInfo are binary compatible (both have same memory layout of fields) then you can do just this:

```
CUserInfo* pui = new CUserInfo;
*pui = *reinterpret_cast<CUserInfo*>(UserInfo);
```

Comment: If one dont know every single field but know the overall layout and size, one can fill those parts with char _unk[n], while n is the number of unknown bytes, to make this approach work

Answer (score 1):

Just something you could do:

```
char* ptr = 0x9F9648;
CUserInfo obj;
obj.clientNum = *((__int32*)ptr);
ptr+=4; // int32 = 4 bytes
// and so on...
```

for arrays you have to read each byte in a loop

```
for(int i=0; i<16; ++i)
{
  obj.Name[i] = *ptr;
  ++ptr;
}
// at this point ptr is updated. No need to increment it
```

`reinterpret_cast` would work too, unless you have pointer fields in you class. If you do I think you have to do as above.

Comment: Hi, i also tried your solution but i'm stuck with char. Can you tell me how to do this with char too? I increased ptr+=12; --- obj.Name = *((char*)ptr); --- But this gives me an error: Cannot convert from char to char[16] --- Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Yes, you need to read each character of a string in a loop. Editing post right now.